# Web part not displayed for newly created forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, form

I have a big/empty sharePoint list with 152 columns. New forms were designed for new/edit/display through SharePoint designer. But none of them was displaying, while the old default forms are displaying without any issue. 
Please see below for the error message display on the webpage
[image]
The new forms are also displaying when a part of the columns/fields are deleted from the newly created forms (not from the list, only the codes for displaying them are deleted), then all the rest can be displayed. This led me to think that there might be some size limitation on the form which does not allow web part to be displayed properly. Any suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all, you may try the proposed solutions here:

- [SharePoint Web Part Error: "Unable to display this web part..."](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31482.sharepoint-web-part-error-unable-to-display-this-web-part.aspx)
- [Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/38e44006-93f4-414f-8016-0a9fbb085730/unable-to-display-this-web-part-to-troubleshoot-the-problem-open-this-web-page-in-a-microsoft)

If non them worked, maybe it means that you are overcoming the column limits, here you have the column limits:

- SharePoint 2010: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#Column
- SharePoint 2013: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#Column

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Now, I am pretty sure it is related to the XSLT transforming time, but we don't have SharePoint server on our site, so, I still have the question about how to tweak the settings.